# Taskwarrior: How do I find the tasks that depend on a specific tasks?

Tags: filter, taskwarrior

How do I find out which task(s) depend on a specific task without reading the information of all tasks?

## Reproduction

### System

Version

```
$ task --version
2.5.1
```

.taskrc

```
# Taskwarrior program configuration file.

# Files
data.location=~/.task

alias.cal=calendar
rc.date.iso=Y-M-D

default.command=ready
journal.info=no
rc.regex=on
```

Here are the tasks that I created for testing purposes:

```
$ task list

ID Age  Description                           Urg 
 1 2min Something to do                          0
 2 1min first do this                            0
 3 1min do this whenever you feel like it        0

3 tasks
```

Create the dependency from task#1 to task#2:

```
$ task 1 modify depends:2
Modifying task 1 'something to do'.
Modified 1 task.

$ task list

ID Age  D Description                           Urg 
 2 4min   first do this                            8
 3 4min   do this whenever you feel like it        0
 1 4min D Something to do                         -5

3 tasks
```

## Goal

Now I want to find the tasks that are dependent on task#2, which should be task#1.

## Trials

Unfortunately, this does not result in any matches:

```
$ task list depends:2
No matches.
```

```
$ # I can filter by blocked tasks
$ task blocked

ID Deps Age   Description    
 1 2    18min Something to do

1 task

$ # But when I want to only have tasks \
    that are blocked by task#2 also task#3 is returned
$ task blocked:2
[task ready ( blocked:2 )]

ID Age   Description                       Urg 
 2 20min first do this                        8
 3 19min do this whenever you feel like it    0

2 tasks
```

## Suggestions?

How would you approach this?
Parsing the taskwarrior output through a script looks like a bit of an overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right command but have actually encountered a [bug](https://github.com/GothenburgBitFactory/taskwarrior/issues/2193): the `depends` attribute does not work with "short id", it's a comma-delimited string of uuids.

It will work if you use UUID instead. Use `task <id> _uuid` to resolve id to UUID.

```bash
$ task --version
2.5.1

# Create tasks
$ task rc.data.location: add -- Something to do
$ task rc.data.location: add -- first do this
$ task rc.data.location: add -- do this whenever you feel like it
$ task rc.data.location: list

ID Age Description                           Urg
 1 -   Something to do                        1.8
 2 -   first do this                          1.8
 3 -   do this whenever you feel like it      1.8
3 tasks

# Set up dependency
$ task rc.data.location: 1 modify depends:2

Modifying task 1 'Something to do'.
Modified 1 task.

# Query using depends:UUID
$ task rc.data.location: list "depends.has:$(task rc.data.location: _get 2.uuid)"

ID Age D Description         Urg
 1 -   D Something to do     -3.2

1 task

# Query using depends:SHORT ID
# This does not work, despite documentation. Likely a bug
$ task rc.data.location: list "depends.has:$(task rc.data.location: _get 2.id)"

No matches.
```

#### Small correction with your trial to find blocked tasks

There is no `blocked` attribute and you're using the `ready` report.

```bash
$ task blocked:2
[task ready ( blocked:2 )]
```

The `ready` report will filter out what we're looking for, the `blocked` report is what we need. To unmagickify this, these are simply useful default reports that have preset filters on top of `task all`.

```
$ task show filter | grep -e 'blocked' -e 'ready'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
report.blocked.filter   status:pending +BLOCKED
report.ready.filter     +READY
report.unblocked.filter status:pending -BLOCKED
```

Blocked tasks will have the virtual tag `+BLOCKED`, which is mutually exclusive to `+READY`.

The `blocked` attribute doesn't exist, use `task _columns` to show available attributes (e.g. `depends`). Unfortunately, the CLI parser is probably attempting to apply the filter `blocked:2` and ends up ignoring it. For your workflow, the useful command to use is `task blocked "depends.has:$(task _get 2.uuid)"`. Advisable to write a shell function to make it easier to use:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Untested but gets the point across
function task_blocked {
  blocker=$1
  shift
  task blocked depends.has:$(task _get ${blocker}.uuid) "$@"
}

# Find tasks of project "foo" that are blocked on task 2
task_blocked 2 project:foo
# What about other project that is also impacted
task_blocked 2 project:bar
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much! That is simply an awesome workaround. Though I somehow abandoned taskwarrior, I think about switching to it again, it gets out of your way so nicely.

Comment: This helped me a lot! But if there is more than one dependency on the task, this won't work since `depends` is a concatianted string. It needs to be `depends.contains:`. See https://github.com/GothenburgBitFactory/taskwarrior/issues/2193#issuecomment-691698687

Comment: @Paul wow great catch! TIL the default is "fuzzy", which seems to be prefix matching.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this taskwarrior hook script that adds a "blocks" attribute to the tasks: https://gist.github.com/wbsch/a2f7264c6302918dfb30

Comment: Thanks, I got this to work, but it seemed to be too complicated for the stuff I want to accomplish. I managed to use the task subjects for the dependencies I have to track down.